# What kind of txtfield to use?

Tags: textfield

I am making an PM system, now I am to where you are going to type the PM.

I dont know really what to use, I don't want to use an normal fugly text field, as theres much nicer stuff out there.

Ive seen those auto expand textfields, that expands more you write? What is this called? Then there's this facebook have, which i also like. And then i have seen this "CKEdtior" stuff, which also seems pretty cool (but i wonder how the output from the CKeditor look like if you use bold, italic, etc..)

Which should I get? What i wish is nice, simple & effective.

Comment: What exactly does this text field need to do?  Just auto expand?  What technology are you using?  What is PM?  Project management?  Personal Message?

Comment: personal message. Yes autoexpanding, maybe also so you could bold,italic,underline text although i would like to know how the output will look like then.. PHP, Javascript, jquery...

Comment: please take a read of ['how to ask a great question'](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints/). This isn't a 'give me the codes' or 'do my work for me' site, you have to invest **some** effort into finding a solution for yourself. Though you could always use [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) to hire someone.

Comment: @David thomas I am not asking to "give me the codes" or "do my work", please read the question again, i am only asking for if they know any nice textfield, that i then myself will work on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [this](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to allow the user to put in stylized text like bold, italic, links etc.  If thats the case there are many editors out there that will turn a stock text area into a full featured editor or even a limited editor.  All the below editor return formatted HTML text.  What you do with it is up to your app.

Try these if you want a word like editor:

xinha.webfactional.com

tinymce.moxiecode.com

ckeditor.com

www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxEditor/index.shtml